# How to identify accusative and dative with personal pronouns?

Tags: grammatical-case, pronoun, personal-pronoun

How to identify accusative and dative cases with personal pronouns? For example:

> Fährst du wirklich im Juli mit *ihm* nach Griechenland?

In this case I find it easy because *mit* goes always with dative but in the other cases how do I know?

> Habt ihr Lust auf nette Leute und gute Musik? Wir nehmen *euch (acc/dat?)* gerne mit zur Party.

Comment: There is no difference in case usage between personal pronouns and nouns; it is _mit ihm_ (dative) and _mit meinem Sohn_ (dative), and _euch mitnehmen_ (accusative) and _ihre Nachbarn mitnehmen_ (accusative). So, what is your question?

Comment: @chirlu, Hans has interpreted the question in an interesting way. If he is correct then your edit has changed the question. Daniel, are you a native speaker? Can you clarify your question? Why did you write "ihn"?

Comment: @Carsten S: Everything is possible. I'll leave it to those who voted _not unclear_ to sort out.

Comment: @chirlu, good response, but how do you vote "not unclear"? I only get how you not vote unclear.

Comment: @Carsten S: I actually meant "selected _Leave Open_ in the close vote review queue", but was too lazy to write that. ;-)

Comment: Es ist MIst, die Frage abzuändern, daß die Antwort dann nicht mehr verständlich ist. Bitte laßt Ihr Besserwisser das bleiben!

Comment: @Karl Wenn der Fragesteller dort wirklich *ihn* gemeint hat, dann benötigt das eine Begründung. Denn der Satz existiert mit *ihn* nicht. Bevor ich versuche, eine kryptische Scheinbedeutung in etwas hineinzulesen, was grammatikalisch erst einmal falsch ist, bessere ich es aus. (Auch wenn ich nicht editiert hab.)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear because it seems to assume that *ihm* is ambiguous as to case in the same way that *euch* is. But it isn't. Accusative and dative of *er* are still distinguishable in standard German: *ihn* vs. *ihm*. (In many dialects this is no longer the case.)

The case system very often provides redundant information. This is one reason why it's generally in a process of dissolution. (In a few dialects there are opposite tendencies.) It doesn't exist because it was ever needed. It exists because it evolved out of postpositions. Postpositions are like prepositions except they are placed after the noun they refer to. They must have been standard once in the evolution of Indo-European, but nowadays we have only a few. (E.g. in English: *ago, aside, notwithstanding*. In German: *zufolge, halber*.)

In the same way that the Indo-European case system with suffixes once evolved out of postpositions, English and French are probably in the process of developing case systems with prefixes right now, out of the prepositions *to/à* and *of/de* and possibly some others. In the case of French *de*, the process of merging with the following word has already started (*d'* before vowels).

Naming the case of a part of speech in a given sentence is not a natural task, so it's not something native speakers are particularly good at. This is why we need the trick described by Daniel B.

The distinction of *ihn* and *ihm* is occasionally relevant. E.g. consider the sentences "Gib den Ball dem Hund", which in context may be shortened to "Gib ihn ihm". Colloquially, someone might actually form the ellipsis "Gib ihn" or "Gib ihm", stressing either what is to be given or the recipient. (Note that for some reason nobody says "Gib ihm ihn", even though "Gib dem Hund den Ball" is actually more common. Just like "Give it him" <s>is normal in English</s> was still normal in Dickens's time and "Give him it" <s>isn't.</s> wasn't.)

It is much harder to come up with a parallel example involving the sequence of words *euch [accusative] euch [dative]*, so in practice it really doesn't matter that accusative and dative are not distinguishable for the second person plural pronouns.

Comment: I contest your assumption that ‘Gib ihm ihn.’ do not exist. I find it natural enough although introduces emphasis on the *ihm*. At the same time, ‘Give it him’ is not a sentence without *to*.

Comment: "Give it him" is of course antiquated, but since it appeared in 19th century parliamentary records and before that many of the best English authors used it, I don't think we should consider it wrong yet. - But normal it isn't any more. True!

Comment: For me, "Gib ihm ihn" only works with extreme emphasis on *ihm*. Note that I didn't actually claim it's ungrammatical. I just said that for some reason nobody says it. And I would actually include the version with stress on *ihm*, since even in that form it seems obsolete to me.

Answer (score 1):

So the rule that works for me is that the Dativ case usually is applied with referring to a location

> ich bin in der Stadt.
>
> ich reite auf dem Pferd.

or the destination of a movement

> ich gebe ihm das Brot.
>
> sie schickt mir eine Nachricht.

Akkusativ usually refers to the object of a sentence when it is not preceded by a dativ preposition (e.g. *zu, mit,* etc.) and does not fulfill the first rule of dative referring to the position of an object at rest or a destination of an object in movement.

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site and visit the [help] for questions about it. While your answer is correct, I don’t know if it will help the OP, because OP explicitly asked for distinctions when using pronouns …

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Doesn't this rule also apply to personal pronouns?

Answer (score 0):

Wenn Du fragen kannst:

> **Wen (oder was)** nehmen wir gerne mit zur Party?

dann ist es Akkusativ.

Dativ erfragt man mit "Wem", also "**Wem** bringen wir etwas mit zur Party? **Dem** Gastgeber."